# Wrapping dynamic elements with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i want to build a chat-like interface with one moderator and all clients listed beside each others shown to the moderator.

i don't know how many of them there will be, so i'm thinking about a `<class="row">`, with dynamically added `col-md-1`s for each client.

but will that wrap for more than 12?

if not, how can i do that?

(add one by one to the right, until the row is full, then proceed in the next line)
i'm looking for a clean & easy bootstrap solution

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. However, you don't have to use .row

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-1">
 </div>
</div>
```

But I suggest using .col-md-2 instead. It looks better.